# Kotlin accessing Java class

Tags: java, android, jvm, kotlin

Why in Kotlin do you need to access they Java class of an object using

```
MyActivity::class.java
```

I have been told is something to do with Kotlin's interoperability with JS ... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `MyActivity::class` returns a `KClass<MyActivity>` object.
This is an extended object that is part of kotlin's expanded reflection capabilities.
Since people also need to access the java class for backwards-compatibility it is included as the field `java` on the `KClass` object.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am now interested in Kotlin's expanded reflection capabilities.

Comment: @fergDEV Kotlin has more runtime information available than typical Java. See:  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html and https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/index.html and https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/index.html